# passing variables without quotes in sql query

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

here's sample code

```
order = 10100

status = 'Shipped'

columnname= 'OrderNumber'

sql = """SELECT  * from orders where %s = %s and status = %s order by %s"""

df1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnx, params=[columnname,order, status,columnname])

"""SELECT  * from orders where 'OrderNumber' = 10100 and status = 'Shipped' order by OrderNumber"""
```

I want to pass variable name and other parameters dynamically. here other parameters passing correctly but columnname parameter i am getting error. as it's passing with quoted string. How to pass parameter without quoted string like below example

```
"""SELECT  * from orders where OrderNumber = 10100 and status = 'Shipped' order by OrderNumber"""
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't parameterize field names, only values. `where %s = %s` - the one on the left of the = won't work

Comment: @Wen that's bad advice, it's open to SQL injection. You shouldn't use string interpolation for the whole query, `%s` here is a placeholder

Comment: no way to parameterize varaible names?

Comment: No, you have to format it into the string yourself. You'll want to check that the value exists in the schema as a means of sanitizing it

Comment: @roganjosh so you mean we can not using format string for dynamic query out the sql ? , I use it a lot in my self-def function ...if so which way  you will suggest

Comment: I would suggest SQLAlchemy https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: @Wen using sqlite as an example (which uses a different placeholder to make it clearer) `c.execute("SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_variable = ?", (the_variable,))`. Note that you're passing a sequence as the second argument. The second argument is unpacked into the placeholders and _automatically escaped_ to prevent it executing any SQL commands that might have been maliciously submitted by the user

Comment: @Wen some SQL libraries use `%s` as a placeholder instead of `?` but it shouldn't be confused with the syntax for string interpolation

Comment: @roganjosh can we pass string as integer in that case quoted string will disappear? i tried but it throwing error cannot convert string to integer.

Comment: Use `int()` on the parameter when you pass it to the query?

Comment: no its throwing the same error. cannot convert.

Comment: Can you please edit in the full traceback for that?

Comment: did you manage to solve your issue?  if yes how i'm running on same :( with postgresql